# how to convert json string to json object in php?

Tags: php, json

Please let me know how to convert json string to json object in php?

I have tried convert json string to json object in php not getting json array properly..

for example:

```
{"return":"{\"catinfo\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"NAME\":\"test1\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"NAME\":\"test2\"}]}"}
```

how to resolve it as like

```
{"catinfo":[{"ID":"1","NAME":"test1"},{"ID":"2","NAME":"test2"}]}"}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$object = json_decode($string);
```

In your case you would like sth like this:

```
$catInfo = json_decode('{"return":"{\"catinfo\":[{\"ID\":\"1\",\"NAME\":\"test1\"},{\"ID\":\"2\",\"NAME\":\"test2\"}]}"}')->return;
```